# Nimbus NIToolbarPhotoViewController Image Crisping Effect

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, nimbus-ios

I'm using [Nimbus](https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus) to display a photo album with scrubber and zoomable image view. I use network images, and display a thumbnail until the final image is loaded. `NIPhotoAlbumScrollView` provides the method `didLoadPhoto:atIndex:photoSize:` to accomplish exactly that.

From the [source code comments](https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus/blob/e9ec6d0db885cb3deda0129921e1cb230d412506/src/photos/src/NIPhotoScrollView.m#L480), the `NIPhotoScrollView` should support that "image crisping effect" - showing thumbnail and when full-size image is loaded, sharpen the image without loosing the zoom state.

This feature seems broken though. When the thumbnail is loaded, it is displayed in its 1:1 pixel size, which is very small on screen. When the full-size image is loaded, it is also loaded in its 1:1 pixel size (if smaller than the available view size), which **makes the image visually jump bigger**.

Any idea on how to fix that issue?

Note that I tried both with a full sized image with dimensions *bigger* or *smaller* than the size of the `NIToolbarPhotoViewController` on screen.

Answer (score 0):

you may already be doing this, but one thing to make certain:

where you implement `photoAlbumScrollView:photoAtIndex:photoSize:isLoading:originalPhotoDimensions:` for protocol `NIPhotoAlbumScrollViewDataSource`, you must do the following, as mentioned in [these comments in the source](https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus/blob/e9ec6d0db885cb3deda0129921e1cb230d412506/src/photos/src/NIPhotoAlbumScrollViewDataSource.h#L54-L55):

```
 * If you have a thumbnail in memory but not the full-size image yet, then you should return
 * the thumbnail, set isLoading to YES, and set photoSize to NIPhotoScrollViewPhotoSizeThumbnail.
```

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that already. Does it work on your side? Which size is the thumbnail displayed at?